# How do I show that only the zero operator satisfies $<Ax,x>=0$ for all vectors $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this may be very easy, but I can't quite figure out the proof of the fact that if $<Ax,x>=0$ for every vector $x$ in an inner product space, the $A=0$. I would thank any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true. Consider "rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$" operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($A(x,y)=(-y,x)$) with standard inner product. The opeartor sends everything to something that's orthogonal to it, so inner product is $0$ but clearly operator is not $0$ opeartor.